# Hadoop distributions

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop. Could you please tell me what are different distributions available for hadoop.

Am seeing standard apache hadoop and Cloudera distribution for hadoop(CDH).

What is the difference between these two? Is CDH free or commercial?

Comment: Apache hadoop is opne source. Look at benchmarking of three major distributors @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482850/difference-between-typical-hadoop-architecture-and-mapr-architecture/32484021#32484021

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Besides Apache Hadoop, it's more or less a three horse race for Hadoop distribution between [HortonWorks](http://hortonworks.com/technology/hortonworksdataplatform/), [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/products-services/) and [MapR](http://www.mapr.com/products). Then there are [GreenPlum HD](http://www.greenplum.com/products/greenplum-hd) and [IBM InfoSphere BigInsights](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/biginsights/).

> Is CDH free or commercial?

CDH from Cloudera is free to use. But, need to pay for any support and management tools on top of CDH.

> What is the difference between these two?

In Apache all the projects (Pig, Hive etc) are independent. Cloudera makes sure all these frameworks work properly with each other and packages them as CDH. With CDH there are regular release, which I haven't seen in Apache. Another thing is it's difficult to get support for Apache Hadoop, while Cloudera and others provide commercial support for their own versions of Hadoop.

Comment: CDH is bound to 50 servers, after that limit you have to pay.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - Could you pl give the reference? I think CDH is available for unlimited nodes, but the SCM Express is free for 50 nodes.

Comment: Oh I missread. It is the Service and Configuration Manager (SCM) which is free until 50 nodes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the inputs. reg statement "CDH from Cloudera is free to use. But, need to pay for any support and management tools on top of CDH"  .. Does it mean their version of hadoop tar file is free to install and use?  I heard they have HUE as a management tool.. Is it free.. are needs to pay for that. Is that HUE works with CDH only?

Comment: Yes - CDH is free as in free to use. Check http://www.cloudera.com/products-services/ for more details.

Comment: very high level comparison of hadoop distributions currently available : http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_book/Distributions.html   (disclaimer : I am an author of this open source hadoop book)

Answer (score -1):

apache hadoop is totally open source
in Cloudera some basic virsions are free if you want more features means we hava to use 
CDH commercial one