# Difference Between typical Hadoop Architecture and MapR architecture

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I know that `Hadoop` is based on Master/Slave architecture

`HDFS` works with `NameNodes` and `DataNodes`

and `MapReduce` works with `jobtrackers` and `Tasktrackers`

But I can't find all these services on `MapR`, I find out that it has its own Architecture with its own services

I'm a little bit confused, could any one please tell me what is the difference between using Hadoop only and using it with MapR !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapR and apache Hadoop DO NOT have same architecture at storage level. MapR uses its own filesystem MaRFS which is completely different from HDFS in terms of concept and implemenation . you can find more detailed comparision here : https://www.mapr.com/blog/comparing-mapr-fs-and-hdfs-nfs-and-snapshots#.VfGwwxG6eUk
https://www.mapr.com/resources/videos/comparison-mapr-fs-and-hdfs

Comment: Mapr uses 80% of Apache distribution as their baseline. See the chart here. http://www.networkworld.com/article/2369327/software/comparing-the-top-hadoop-distributions.html

Comment: MapR does support computational tools comes from Apache but it is completely different from Storage (Files system) point of view and cluster services (this questions context)

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 7):

You have to refer to `Hadoop 2.x` latest architecture since `YARN` ( Yet Another Resource Negotiator) & `High Availability` have been introduced in 2.x version.

***Job tracker and Task tracker are replaced with Resource Manager, Node Manager and Applications Manager***.

[Hadoop 2.x YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) & [High Availability](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html)

For `MapR` architecture, refer to [MapR](https://www.mapr.com/why-hadoop/why-mapr/architecture-matters) article

For comparison between different distributors, refer to this image

[image]

Detailed comparison is available at [Data-magnum](http://data-magnum.com/cloudera-vs-hortonworks-vs-mapr-has-mapr-already-won-this-contest/) article by  `Bill Vorhies`

Answer (score 3):

Mapr uses most of Apache bigdata distributions as their baseline. 
[image]
Mapr is a hadoop (and bigdata technology stacks) distribution provider with certain add-ons and technical support to its client.

Underline the mapr is entirely on the same architecture as of apache hadoop including all the core library distribution. However mapr distribution is more like a bundle of a complete and compatible bigdata technology package.

The main benefit of mapr is that it's distribution of various technologies like hive, hbase, spark etc will be compatible with core hadoop and among each other. This I'd particularly important because the bigdata technologies are evolving in different pace and hence news releases becomes incompatible very soon.

So, the vendors like mapr, cloudera etc are providing their version of hadoop didtribution and support such that end users can concentrate on the product building without worrying about the compatibility issues. But almost all of them are using apache distribution under the carpet.

In future, they might come up certain variation and additional features in an attempt to prevent client's switch to other vendors, but as of now is not the case.

Comment: MapR and apache Hadoop DO NOT have same architecture at storage level.
MapR uses its own filesystem MaRFS which is completely different from HDFS in terms of concept and implemenation .

you can find more detailed comparision here : https://www.mapr.com/resources/videos/comparison-mapr-fs-and-hdfs
https://www.mapr.com/blog/comparing-mapr-fs-and-hdfs-nfs-and-snapshots#.VfGrUBG6eUk

Comment: @Pradeep, Did I say Mapr and apache distribution is exactly same? Can you confirm that Mapr has their proprietary version of all of their Bigdata platform and has not taken Apache distribution as baseline?

Comment: I said they are not same at the storage level . Concept of storing data in MapRFS and HDFS is completely different. Above diagram compares the computational tools (not storage part). MapR does support majorly all computational tools(like MR, hive ,pig etc..) which comes from apache.

The question asked was in context of HDFS architecture.