# Which distribution - HDP or CDH - should I use for free cluster deployment that focusses on Spark and security?

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I am a beginner in big data, and may be this a question more for Quora, but I'll still go ahead and shoot. I have to set up a realtime data streaming cluster, strict on security requirements (role based access, encrypted transmission and storage). The plan is to use Apache Kafka for the data pipeline that sends data to Spark streaming, over which we run some analysis or visualisations, etc. So the questions I want answered are

1. What are the best options for setting up such a cluster using an existing distribution like Cloudera's or HortonWorks' (or DIY?)  I want to stay open source and free, so not looking for MapR.  A setup that is or can be integrated with Kafka and Spark is what i am looking for here.
2. What are the security implementations for the distribution suggested above (for role based access, encryption at all layers)
3. What is the overhead introduced with security features added?
4. How to benchmark or test such a cluster, that is, any links,guides for tutorials, and virtual setups to play with?
5. If I go for Cloudera's CDH 5 with Cloudera Manager Express, what features will I not be able to integrate in my cluster; as opposed to Cloudera Manager Enterprise edition?

Comment: You may find some answers for your queries : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482850/difference-between-typical-hadoop-architecture-and-mapr-architecture/32484021#32484021

Comment: thanks, insightful, however the verdict there seems MapR which is an enterprise product. Any leads on this specific use case among the 2 distributions?

Comment: why the negative vote, please explain at least, it is taking some required accesses

Comment: I have faced this kind of voting when I am new to stackoverflow.. If a question is too broad & possible multiple answers, then someone else will down vote it. Some times these questions will be closed and deleted. Some visitors of this site might have probably down voted your questions on this basis.